# CSS focus: Is there a way to unfocus?

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm playing about with focus in my css as I am thinking of doing a drop down list with this. I am however having a problem with the "unfocus": at the moment it will unfocus if you click outside of the div.inside which is what I want. However, I also want to make it unfocus when you click again on the li.collapse, so that the li.collapse is like an on/off button.

I tried this with no luck:

```
div.inside:active + li.collapse:focus { display: none;}
```

Does anyone know another way around this or is it even possible without JavaScript?

Here is the code and fiddle:

html:

```
<li class=collapse tabindex="1"><a>&nbsp;Click To See List&nbsp;</a> <div class="inside">
List 1....</div></li>
```

css:

```
li.collapse > a{background: #cdf; cursor: pointer; display: block;}
li.collapse:focus{ outline: none;}
li.collapse > div.inside{ display: none;}
li.collapse:focus div.inside{display: block; }
div.inside:focus{ display: none;}
div.inside{background: #cdf; }
div.inside:active + li.collapse:focus { display: none;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q2e1vnny/

Comment: I believe you will need JS for this

Comment: Tangential notes: • missing the quotes around `collapse`. • using css to add padding around an element is typically considered preferable to using `&nbsp`s. • unless you need to distinguish `div.collapse` from `somethingelse.collapse` it's good practice (speeds browser load time, and makes it easier to override the styles) to just say `.collapse` (and `.inside`). • unless you need to distinguish `.collapse > a` from `.collapse a`, it's good practice (same reasons) to avoid `>`. • `+` [selects adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: The opposite of `focus` is `blur` [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use JavaScript to programmatically focus and blur elements. CSS will only allow you to style elements that have had an event occur on them.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('SomeId').focus();
document.getElementById('SomeId').blur();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick i just found and i think you can do, just set:

```
li.collapse:focus
{ pointer-events: none; }
```

And make sure there is an object under your `li` which can be focused.

Some adjusments may be required depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript. For getting your toes wet, I recommend jQuery (in this particular example it doesn't make much difference, but if you start reading about one or the other I think jQuery will be an easier place to start. Cue the disagreers!).

Here's an example of how I would do this if I needed to support more than one item. That's more than your example requires, and this might be too different for you to use (it doesn't rely on `:focus` at all, and I don't know if a javascript solution is acceptable for your project), but hopefully it'll be useful for your thinking about lists and css and js.

- Where you used `<div>` I'm using `<li>` ("list item"), and where you used `<li>` I'm using `<ul>` ("unordered list").
- Nested lists help keep it semantic ("There's a list, and each list can have a sublist")
- The jQuery script says "when a `<span>` is clicked, add the class "open" if it doesn't have it otherwise remove the class "open."
- The CSS says "hide sublists, but show lists that immediately follow elements with the class "open"

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open')
})
```

```css
ul > li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cdf;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
}
.open + ul {
  display: block;
}

/* layout styles to match your example */
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: inside;
}
li li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Click 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>a link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>another link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Click 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>a link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>another link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>yet another link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See https://api.jquery.com/click/ for more about jQuery's `click()`, including examples.